# sending notification through FCM token?

Tags: django, firebase

I login through an app which update the FCM token in my backend server. Now i have another end point which sends the notification which i am hitting through postman. What should be the authorization token in this case, would it be user access token or fcm token?

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the authorization token in this case, would it be user access token or fcm token?

It should be your `authorization token`

the only time when you need `FCM` token is when you are sending notification, and you put this `FCM` inside the payload

You are as a user shouldn't even know your `FCM` token, so sending this token through postman is wrong. It should be stored in database, and triggered when needed according to your `authorization token`